# Installing Mono on Amazon Linux AMI

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ami, mono

I am trying to setup an Amazon EC2 AMI ([details](http://thecloudmarket.com/image/ami-8c1fece5--amzn-ami-2011-02-1-i386-ebs#/definition)) with Mono 2.8.2 on it by following [this guide](http://www.claassen.net/geek/blog/2010/12/installing-mono-2-8-1-on-amazon-linux-ami-1-0.html). I've run into a couple of issues with it.

**Issue One**

I get a `Permission Denied` error When I try to do the following steps

```
cat >>/etc/profile.d/mono_path.sh
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/mono-2.8.1/bin
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/mono-2.8.1/lib/pkgconfig/:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH
```

Even doing `sudo cat >>/etc/profile.d/mono_path.sh` resulted in the same `Permission Denied` error so I decided to use VI to create a /etc/profile.d/mono_path.sh and added in the above two lines to it.

**Issue Two**

When trying to install **XSP-2.8.1** I need to use `sudo` to run the following command

```
./configure –prefix=/opt/mono-2.8.1
```

It fails with the following error output

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-245-39-133 xsp-2.8.1]$ sudo ./configure –prefix=/opt/mono-2.8.1
checking build system type… i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type… i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking target system type… i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install… /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane… yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p… /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk… gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)… yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles… no
checking for a BSD-compatible install… /usr/bin/install -c
checking for pkg-config… /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking if tracing is requested… no
checking for csc… no
checking for gmcs… no
checking for dmcs… no
checking for runtime in the installation prefix… /opt/mono-2.8.1/bin/mono
checking for gacutil… no
checking for sn… no
configure: error: No C# compiler found
```

Now I have no idea how to get around this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: One question per question, please.  Multiple questions means you can't pick an accepted answer, and makes reading the answers difficult for everyone.

Answer (score 2):

`sudo cat >>/etc/profile.d/mono_path.sh` only runs `cat` as root, with the redirection happening as the original user.  The equivalent in sudoland is `cat | sudo tee -a /etc/profile.d/mono_path.sh`

Comment: Thanks, what about the second issue though? since that issue is the bigger problem.

Comment: FFS, if I knew the answer, don't you think I would have given it?

Comment: I suppose I did not consider that possibility.

Comment: Whilst my skills are considerable (if I do say so myself), they are not infinite.

Answer (score 1):

A better way to install mono is found in this [article](http://www.groovbird.com/2011/03/setting-up-mono-on-amazon-ec2.html). Took me a few minutes to install the mono binaries, just need to add the mono_path.sh file which should contain two lines:-

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/novell/mono/bin
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/novell/mono/lib/pkgconfig/:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH
```

Now to run the Terraria server which my kid wanted a while ago!